# Adding user to a particular branch in Perforce

Tags: perforce, perforce-branch-spec

How can I give access to only a set of users to edit a particular perforce branch after I created it? I am not the admin of perforce but only the creator of the branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions need to be set by a Perforce admin user unfortunately, using the [p4 protect](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_protect.html) command.